# How can i serve multiple static content using Nginx server?

Tags: nginx

I am newbie trying out Nginx and hence the question might be silly.

**Requirement:**

How can a single HTTP call to an Nginx server retrieve multiple static content?

For example: http://localhost.com:80/data/test should be retrieving files 'A', 'B', ... 'Z'.

Also, can we implement URL pagination using Nginx. 
http://localhost.com:80/data?index=100 fetches 100 documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing different things.

An HTTP response can include whatever data you'd like, but you can't return multiple responses to a single request.

It sounds like you may be thinking of serving out documents. In that case, the `index=100` parameter would simply inform your `/data` application that you (the requester) would like to see 100 documents. The `/data` application would then format an appropriate response-in this example, a web page containing links to 100 documents.